# Session based CSRF Tokens - What value do i use with JWT?

Tags: csrf, session-management, jwt, hmac

The [Double Submit Cookie](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#double-submit-cookie) CSRF Token pattern is a stateless technique that doesn't require storage or a database. However, it's vulnerable to session hijacking attacks and sub-/sibling domains that are susceptible to XSS or HTML injection. A common way to mitigate this risk is by using a session value and signing it using HMAC to validate the authenticity of the request.

For backend programming languages that don't natively support sessions (such as NodeJS) or when not Database is available, JWT is commonly used with `HttpOnly` Cookies to persist authorization across multiple requests. However, note that while the JWT value can't be tampered with because it's a signed value, it's not a server-side secret and can be read by the client.

Given these considerations, what value unique to a session can be used to generate the HMAC CSRF Token when using JWT?

Some possibilities I thought about were:

- attaching a random UUID in the JWT payload and encrypting the JWT, but this approach adds a lot of overhead
- use a database to store session IDs, but this negates the need for JWT in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'm afraid your statement saying that Node.js has no support sessions is semi-false - express.js has sessions for example, which is commonly used. If by natively you mean part of the standard library - then you might be right there, but it doesn't matter, since you need to use at least some libraries or frameworks either way..

Comment: P.S. have you looked into JWS? It might solve some of your issues.

Comment: Node.js is not a language, but a runtime. It uses JavaScript as language.

Comment: Please explain what problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: @SirMuffington Express is a framework for NodeJS, which needs an additional [first-party library to be installed.](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html)
There are many other web frameworks for Node.js, other than Express, that only have access to a session with the help of third-party libraries, sometimes leading to brittle implementations.

Comment: @mentallurg excuse my mix-up of correct terminology. Of course, Node.js is a runtime that uses JavaScript. I was using NodeJS as an example for server-side code that stores the user session in a stateless JSON Web Token. The problem I'm trying to solve is what safe techniques can be used, when using JWT, to bind the CSRF Token with the current session, besides the ones I mentioned.

Comment: @Tanckom: You say **what** are you going to do, but you still don't explain **why**. What problem do you have?

Comment: @mentallurg to generate a signed CSRF Token that is session bound when JWT is used to authorize and no server-side session is available. Commonly, you find username, email and other static values in the JWT payload. But let's say that we add a random value to the JWT payload, that changes for each session. This session value is now openly readable and not a secret, like a server-side session. My concern is that I open up for vulnerabilities with such an approach, unknown to me and therefore look for alternative techniques.

Comment: CSRF token should not be available to any other application. But I still don't understand what problem are you trying to solve. Why are you looking for some manipulations with CSRF token? Why don't you use double submit cookie approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145054/discussion-between-tanckom-and-mentallurg).

Answer (score -1):

I think I have found the answer to my question.

Let's take a closer look at what we consider to be secure value to use for a session-bound CSRF token: the session id of a server-side session.

When a session is started in the backend, all session data is stored server-side and assigned a unique ID. This ID is then stored in an `HttpOnly` Cookie, which means that the session ID is stored in plain text client-side. It just can't be read by JavaScript, but you can easily inspect it with the Browser's devtool.

Now, the JWT is also stored in a `HttpOnly` Cookie. The values, just like the server-side session id, are stored in plain-text client side (unless the JWT is encrypted). In other words, we can quite safely store a unique ID (a random value) in the JWT that only exists for the lifetime of the JWT. We can then use this unique ID for as the session for the CSRF token.

In both cases, the value we use for session signed CSRF tokens is available client-side, but there is no need to worry. In both cases, the backend has the secret key to sign the CSRF token, making it impossible for an attacker to forge a signed CSRF Token, even if they have knowledge of the session ID or unique ID in a JWT.

Comment: *"The values, just like the server-side session id, can be read client side"* - No. You say that the session ID cookie has HttpOnly attribute set. This means that such cookie **cannot be read** by the client. This is the **purpose** of HttpOnly attribute, to prevent client from reading such cookies.

Comment: *"store a unique ID (a random value) in the JWT"* - How does it prevent CSRF?

Comment: *"a session-bound CSRF token: the session id of a server-side session"* - Do you mean that you suggest to use session ID as a CSRF token? If not, please explain it.

Comment: *"backend has the secret key to sign the CSRF token"* - What is the goal of signing the CSRF token? Why do you think that just a random string is not sufficient?

Comment: Please explain: 1) how you generate CSRF token; 2) how is it transferred to the client; 3) where is it stored on the client; 4) how is it sent from the client to the server.

Comment: Also please explain why do you want to bind JWT to session. JWT is usually issued by a separate server, Identity Provider. It is a bad idea if resource server would tell Identity Provider session ID. If you don't have separate Identity Provider and JWT is issued by the resource server itself, then JWT makes no sense, because you already use session ID generated by *the same* server.

Comment: [Let us continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145054/discussion-between-tanckom-and-mentallurg)